# What mathmetics behind the expression console.log(1&3);

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working with angularjs and there is this pieceof code. I dont get What does it return?

```
    authorize: function(accessLevel, role) {
        if(role === undefined) {
            role = Session.role;
        }
        return accessLevel.bitMask & role.bitMask;
    },
```

Some tests

```
        console.log(1&2);     //0
        console.log(3&7);     //3
        console.log(5&11);    //1
        console.log(0.5&11);  //0
```

Anyone has any idea?

Edit: I am sorry that this question was already asked. But since i didnt know the keyword bitwise, or couldnt find any match with the previous topic keywords in my presearch i appriciate the answers here!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it very simply, `&` is a [bit-wise `AND`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation. The `return` expression is checking whether the bits in `role` "jive" with the bits in `accessLevel` (i.e. is this role authorized?).

To add some detail, let's look at this line:

```
console.log(3&7);     //3
```

In bit-land, we have:

```
3: 00000011
7: 00000111
===========
&: 00000011 = 3
```

The result of the bit-wise `AND` operation on the two bytes is arrived at by `AND`-ing each bit column based on these rules:

```
0 & 0 => 0
0 & 1 => 0
1 & 0 => 0
1 & 1 => 1
```

If you think of each `0` as `false` and each `1` as `true`, then it makes a lot of sense. See the Wikipedia article on [Truth tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of
>   both operands are ones.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators